# How to get the first line in a paragraph

Tags: ios, swift, string, split

I am developing a iOS mobile app where my requirement is to get the first line of the paragraph and change its font from the rest of the paragraph.  For e.g. - If I have a paragraph as -

let sampleString = "IS1 This is sample text.

This sample text is good. This requires to split the String into two parts. The first line is has different text from rest."

I have tried to use -

```
let stringToSplit = sampleString.characters.split(".").map(String.init)
```

But the result I am getting is - 
First part is coming as - 
IS1 This is sample text.

Remaining String is coming as -
This requires to split the String into two parts. The first line is has different text from rest.

The line "This sample text is good." is not showing up.

Can you please help. XCode 8.0, Swift 2.3

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Separate the string by the newline `CharacterSet`, that preserves also the trailing period.

```
if let firstParagraph = sampleString.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.newlines).first {
    print(firstParagraph)
}
```

Then you can get the range of the first paragraph in `sampleString`

```
let range = sampleString.range(of: firstParagraph)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use following method as well to split the string

```
let stringToSplit = sampleString.components(separatedBy: ".")
```

It will return you array of components separated by given character. `stringToSplit[0]` will give you first sentence

Comment: Let me know if this is correct - `var stringToSplit = sampleString.components(separatedBy: ".")

stringToSplit.remove(at: 0)

let stringRepresentation = stringToSplit.joined(separator: ".")

print(stringRepresentation)`

Comment: Be careful using a period as a separator. For example a sentence like "There are over 100 U.S. lightning-strike deaths each year." will probably not yield what you want.